# Using the property of another type in a type definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm reading through [this article](https://engineering.datorama.com/building-a-shopping-cart-in-angular-using-akita-c41f6a6f7255) and it has the following type definition in it:

```
 export type CartItem = {
   productId: Product['id'];
   quantity: number;
   total: number;
};
```

I'm assuming that this means that the `productId` property has to have the same type as the type assigned to `product['id']`?  Just for reference it is defined like this:

```
export type Product = {
   id: ID;
   title: string;
   description: string;
   price: number;
};
```

Comment: Yes, it's called a [lookup type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Product['id']` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) (also known as a lookup type) that gets the type of the field `id` of the type `Product`, which is `ID`.

Comment: Wow - Typescript bends the spoon!  Thanks!